# Equal sign that is not in formula

Tags: texmaker

I need to input an SQL query in my text; something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 0
```

However, LaTeX asks me to put a `$` sign around, because of equal sign. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to make the query from the LaTeX compilation or just type to code in order to show how to use SQL (i.e. a listing?)

Comment: _Who_ asks _what_?

Answer (score 6):

The equals sign does not cause trouble in text mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 0
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Maybe some other character causes the trouble, for example, the underscore `_`. This can be set via `\_` or `\textunderscore`.

An alternative is verbatim input (also changes the font):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\verb|SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE ID = 0|
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result verbatim]

Or package `listings` can be used even with syntax highlighting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstinline|SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE ID = 0|

\lstinline[language=SQL]|SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE ID = 0|
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result listings]

Comment: why the downvote?  this is how latex *should* behave; if texmaker is not allowing it, then something is wrong.

Comment: I think there's something else going on here in the user's code...